# p:autocomplete completemethod isn't fired with copy-pate with mouse events

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

I am using [primefaces autocomplete component](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/autoComplete.xhtml).
My problem is when I copy and **paste** in that component (with mouse) not with **ctrl + V** , nothing happens , complete method is not fired and no list returns.

Is there a way to make mouse copy-paste behave like keyboard events with **p:autocomplete**?

This is a piece of code I am working on

```
<p:autoComplete size="20" minQueryLength="3" id="quickSearch" styleClass="quickSearch"
        value="#{bean.value}" completeMethod="#{bean.searchList}" var="object"
        itemValue="#{object}" itemLabel="#{object.objectCode}" converter="complexConverter"
        style="margin-left: -50;" forceSelection="true" widgetVar="quickSearchVar"
        emptyMessage="No Results Found..">
    <p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{bean.goToObject()}"></p:ajax>
    <p:column>
        ...
        ...
    </p:column>
</p:autoComplete>
```

And this is where I am trying to capture the copy-paste events

```
$('.quickSearch').on('paste', function() {
    // alert('hello');
    // here I need to trigger what I am asking for
});
```

And I am wondering if somebody can explain to me what event fires the complete method and returns the suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you're currently working with.

Comment: @FredGandt Done

Comment: @HebaA. Wondering, I am also using `p:autoComplete`, but did not observe such behavior. What version of PrimeFaces are you using?

Comment: Also, could you please share the complete method and converter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PrimeFaces's `autoComplete` widget has a method called `showSuggestions` to call it from a javascript function you can use the `widgetVar` value of your component

```
PF('quickSearchVar').showSuggestions(PF('quickSearchVar').input.val())
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my workaround to make mouse paste behave like keyboard events:

```js
$('quickSearch').on('paste', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('quickSearch').keyup();
  }, 100);
});
```